# Parsing multiple valus in multiple variables

Tags: powershell

I am trying to find a way to execute a command in powershell and put each line of the result in a different variable to use them later in my script. For example if i execute the below command:

```
C:\> Get-VMHost -Name hq-esxi-prod-01a.nsx.gss | Get-VM | select Name
```

I will get the below:

```
Name          
----          
HQ-LinServ-01a
HQ-Win2012-01a
HQ-Web-02a
```

I want to have a script that will add each line in a different variable in a script (excluding the first which is name).

how can i do that.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Set-Variable` in a loop to put each value in a separate variable:

```
$i = 0
... | Get-Vm | Select-Objet -Expand Name | ForEach-Object {
  Set-Variable -Name "vm$i" -Value $_
  $i++
}
```

However, that usually isn't good advice. It's more common to put all names in one (array) variable:

```
$vmList = ...| Get-Vm | Select-Object -Expand Name
```

so you can access individual names via `$vmList[<index>]`, or (if you need access by some kind of name) in a hashtable:

```
$i = 0
$vmList = @{}
... | Get-Vm | Select-Objet -Expand Name | ForEach-Object {
  $vmList["vm$i"] = $_
  $i++
}
```

Best practice would depend on the particular scenario you need this for, though.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply,
I have tried you answer but it seems that i am using PowerCLI for VMware it does not include Select-Object -Expand (not sure i had an exception), However your answer have mad me reach to a suitable answer for this.

I have used the below and it worked fine using foreach and adding the values in an array and then reading them as below:

```
$p1vmname = Get-VMHost -Name hq-esxi-prod-01a.nsx.gss | Get-VM | select Name
$p1vmlist = @()
foreach ($p1line in $p1vmname)
            {
            $p1vmlist += $p1line
            }
                $p1 = 0
                do {
                $x = $p1+1
                Write-Host -BackgroundColor:Black -ForegroundColor:Yellow "vm number $x is "$p1vmlist[$p1]"."
                $p1++
                } 
                until ($p1 -eq $p1vmc)
                }
```

However when using this the names was not totally correct as they had some additional characters as below:

```
vm number 1 is @{Name=HQ-Web-01a}
vm number 2 is @{Name=HQ-LinServ-01a}
vm number 3 is @{Name=HQ-Win2012-01a}
```

so i used split and trim to get rid of these as below and worked fine.

```
$p1vmname = Get-VMHost -Name hq-esxi-prod-01a.nsx.gss | Get-VM | select Name
$p1vmlist = @()
foreach ($p1line in $p1vmname)
            {
            $p1vmlist += $p1line
            }
                $p1 = 0
                do {
                $x = $p1+1
                $p1vmlist[$p1] = ($p1vmlist[$p1]) -split("=") | Select-Object -Last 1
                $p1vmlist[$p1] = $p1vmlist[$p1].trimend("}")
                Write-Host -BackgroundColor:Black -ForegroundColor:Yellow "vm number $x is "$p1vmlist[$p1]"."
                $p1++
                } 
                until ($p1 -eq $p1vmc)
                }
```

Output:

```
vm number 1 is  HQ-Web-01a .
vm number 2 is  HQ-LinServ-01a .
vm number 3 is  HQ-Win2012-01a .
```

Thank you so much for your answer that helped me a lot.

I am really enjoying scripting now.